# Equivalent "openssl_seal" for .NET?

Tags: c#, php, encryption, ssl, openssl

I'm desperately looking for a .NET (C#) code equivalent of PHP's "openssl_seal" (http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-seal.php) functionality. A few hours of googling around, trying out OpenSSL and BouncyCastle .NET APIs didn't turn up much or I'm not tackling it all from the right direction.

My understanding is that PHP "openssl_seal" command does the following (this is a quote from their site):

1. Generates a random key (128 bit)
2. Encrypts the data symmetrically with RC4 using the random key
3. Encrypts the random key itself with RSA using the public key/certificate
4. Returns the encrypted data and the encrypted key.

Which is all fine and dandy but leaves a lot of room for interpretation and subtle innacuracies. Matching the results from both PHP and C# via trial-and-error is a daunting prospect (also the key is "random" so that won't even work) :) Has anyone been actually able to successfully accomplish replicating "openssl_seal" mechanism via C#?

Comment: Are you looking for a multi-key RC4 implementation in C#? You'd be better served explaining what your need (desperate, yes) requires you to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My rant on the solution for this nugget: http://geekswithblogs.net/Strenium/archive/2013/01/27/converting-phprsquos-ldquoopenssl_sealrdquo-and-ldquoopenssl_openrdquo-into-.net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/interop.html

That might help. Click on PHP Bindings / openssl_seal() / openssl_open(). Then click on phpseclib under "Seal" with.

What you said sounds pretty accurate. You encrypt the RC4 key using PKCS1 padding.

Good luck!